# Why does this OpenGL app run horrendously slowly on certain Macs?

Tags: macos, opengl, graphics, rust, glsl

I wrote a little fractal video feedback app. It runs fine on old laptops running Linux or Windows 10. It runs fine on my Android phone. It runs fine on a desktop Hackintosh. But on certain MacBooks, it runs at literally 0.02 FPS and uses a whole CPU core (should use a few %).

I assume that I'm using some shader feature that causes it to drop down to software rendering, but what could that be? The shaders are not doing anything very fancy; you can [see the source code here](https://github.com/kmcallister/azurescens/tree/master/src/shaders). The shaders use `#version 150` on non-GLES platforms.

The program just draws 6 triangles per frame: two ping-pong between textures, and one copy to the screen. The CPU-side Rust code is also in that repo.

Does anyone know what could cause this issue, or what tools I could use to track it down?

Answer (score 2):

You can force your OpenGL context to use only a hardware renderer by specifying certain pixel format attributes when you create it. As described in [Technical Q&A QA1502 Ensuring hardware accelerated rendering for your OpenGL application](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1502/_index.html):

> A simple way to select a hardware accelerated renderer without the choice of software fallback is by selecting the following pixel format attributes:
>
> For CGL:
>
> `kCGLPFAAccelerated` and `kCGLPFANoRecovery`
>
> For AGL:
>
> `AGL_ACCELERATED` and `AGL_NO_RECOVERY`
>
> For NSOpenGL:
>
> `NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated` and `NSOpenGLPFANoRecovery`

QA1502 also describes how you can ask the content whether it is using the GPU for vertex and fragment processing.

You can consult Apple's [OpenGL Capabilities Tables](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/OpenGL-Capabilities-Tables.pdf) to see if you're using a feature that is not supported in your target hardware. Note that this document contains three tables (for 10.7.5, 10.8.5, and 10.9), each of which is several pages long. Either there have been no changes in macOS OpenGL hardware capabilities since 10.9, or Apple just hasn't bothered documenting them.

There's also a link to the tables as a Numbers spreadsheet on Apple's [OpenGL for macOS](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/) developer page.

If you're looking at the capabilities tables, you'll probably find [this document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823) useful for figuring out which GPU hardware is in your target Mac.

You can use the OpenGL Profiler to see what OpenGL calls your app is issuing and how long they take. This might help you figure out what's wrong. The OpenGL Profiler is part of [Additional Tools for Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

However, the profiler has been broken for all of macOS Sierra's lifetime: it makes your app crash if you try to attach to the running app, and it never finishes attaching if you use the profiler to launch your app. I investigated the problem with the responsible Apple engineer at WWDC 2017 and we found that the profiler in “Additional Tools for Xcode 9 beta” works in macOS Sierra 10.12.5, but not in macOS High Sierra 10.13 beta 1. So if you're running macOS Sierra, use that version.

Apparently the problem is that Apple keeps creating entitlements (restrictions) that the profiler needs in order to work properly, without issuing new profiler versions signed with those entitlements. I expect a version of the profiler that works with High Sierra to be available by beta 3 (maybe beta 2, but probably not).